# Java how to close program and move to anther one from a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have made a normal window with an image. I was wondering how to make a button saying "Click here to start" which when pressed will close the program and launch another program.

Comment: Do you want to launch another program or launch another window within the same program?

Comment: Define *"will close the program and launch the other program"*?  Are you executing a external process or trying to open another Java Window?

Comment: Sorry ye i meant that it will launch the second bit of my code, which is like a math game , so ye it will bring up anther window

Comment: Ali your question in danger of being closed because you are asking for the solution for a sizable problem without demonstrating any effort to build the pieces yourself.  Are you asking how to call other applications, how to connect events to GUI actions, what GUI tool are you using, etc.

Comment: Thank u @MadProgrammer very good helpm and at Eddie i have tried this but i have failed hence why i have asked for help on here. I did not see the point of posting the code as it would not even complie but people are very helpfull and i understand it now. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by having a look at [How to use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and also have a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

This will allow you to have a single window and reduce the amount of switching code you would need

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleDemo();
    }

    public SimpleDemo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(cardLayout);

                JPanel startPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
                startPanel.add(startButton);
                startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "game");
                    }
                });

                JLabel game = new JLabel("Game On", JLabel.CENTER);

                frame.add(startPanel, "start");
                frame.add(game, "game");

                cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "start");

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To hide a window but keep the resources behind it, use the `JFrame.setVisible(false)`. To completely get rid of it, use the `dispose()` method.

To launch your new window, use code similar to what you used to launch your first window.

There are many resources available online and on [this website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233711/how-to-make-simple-java-buttons) that will help you learn how to create a button, including [Oracle's own site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html):

Answer (score 0):

Simply call main(String[]) on your second program to start it. If the current one is no longer required, call dispose() on its frame.

The classes of your second program must be in class path. This is easy to arrange by writing an appropriate bash/bat startup scrips or you can bundle all classes in the single jar.