# How to open a new window by clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

As a part of my program, I need to have a button that when the user click on it, it opens a new window.

Well I guess I should have a class that make the frame and call it by the button. but I don't have any idea to start. I just got my button in the program, but it does not work. So can some tell me how to do it? or code it.

Comment: Also check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512876/java-how-to-close-program-and-move-to-anther-one-from-a-gui) question which was just asked

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  +1 @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simplified version of what you want to do:

```
JButton button = new JButton("New Frame");
button.addActionListener( new ActionActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Create a method named "createFrame()", and set up an new frame there
        // Call createFrame()
    }
});
```

You would probably want to call some method in the `ActionListener` rather than make the `frame` on `actionPerformed`. Maybe something like this:

```
public static void createFrame()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                try 
                {
                   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                panel.setOpaque(true);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 50);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textArea.setEditable(false);
                textArea.setFont(Font.getFont(Font.SANS_SERIF));
                JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
                inputpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
                JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
                DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
                caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
                panel.add(scroller);
                inputpanel.add(input);
                inputpanel.add(button);
                panel.add(inputpanel);
                frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                input.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }
```

What that frame should look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you reply and time. Im kinda confused with your solution.  for the button I exactly copied what you provided. on the other hand I made a class and designed the layout of the new window. So do not know how to call it by the action listener. and what to put in the new window page to link it to the button.

Comment: @AlexJj Make sure you have all your imports in order, and that if you have `createFrame()` in another class, you call it with `Classname.createFrame()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
new CLASS_NAME().setVisible(true);
```

eg. new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);